# Should I have handled this situation better?

Tags: discussion, downvote-reason

I downvoted [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279537/elements-will-not-center-within-a-div/32279616?noredirect=1#answer-32279616) and flagged it as not an answer because it was merely commentary on the OP's original post. As I've come to expect from lower reputation users, there was a fury of backlash as though we were attacking the individual. I don't believe this to be the true, at least in the case of my downvote. I can't speak for others.

This time I tried something a little different. Rather than posting a snarky response when the OP responded to my comment, I reached out to guide the user in the proper direction. I recommended specific documentation and explained why their usage of the *answer* box was an inappropriate one and how circumventing the rules by commenting in said box can deteriorate the quality of the site.

No such luck. It's as if, my responses weren't even being read. As such I, reflagged the question specifically for moderator attention in the hopes that maybe they could provide a different, and possibly, better perspective on the issue than I did.

So my question is, should I have handled the situation differently? Should I not have responded and not provided any indication as to why the question was incorrect or how to fix it? I'm all for helping new users. The more programmers the better. I feel like this was more of a [kobayashi maru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru) scenario though. Any advice or just better luck next time?

Comment: From what I saw before it was deleted, it looked like you handled that really well. You didn't insult the answerer, you merely explained why that was not an answer, and even provided some instruction on how to improve the post. When they asked for documentation to back up your point, your comment was calm and you did indeed point to a help center page that did back up your point. Some people just don't like being told they can't do a thing they're trying to do.

Comment: Well, your first comment would have been better if it had acknowledged that he cannot comment yet. Aside from that, everything after your second comment (by everyone) was not useful, imho. And I agree with @Kendra, though I could still look at it if I wanted.

Comment: You should a ridiculous amount of patience towards that user. Keep it up!

Comment: Please avoid piling on to this user. They have only been here for 3 days and are probably still trying to figure out how the system works. I believe at this point they have probably come to understand to no longer post comments as answers.

Comment: my advise would be to _not_ go into a debate: you made your point in the first comment (which you might improve a bit by acknowledging that the user right now can't yet do the optimal but will in near future when s/he contributes _by_ the rules - that not being an excuse to break them) and simply flag/downvote/delete with all the tools that are available to you. Then move on.

Comment: ... Was the inappropriate behaviour of that user rewarded by [random pity upvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5267785/sharad-saxena?tab=reputation)?

Comment: I don't think you did anything bad or wrong.  I also think it might have been better to disengage sooner.  The author of that non-answer was in such an agitated state that they perceived the comments as "flaming" instead of constructive criticism.  Trying to tell someone something they don't want to hear is likely to be a waste of time.

Comment: There's ALWAYS something you could have done better . . . but that doesn't mean that if only you had improved XYZ enough, it would have been a favorable outcome. Feel free to solicit improvement from SE experts on how you could have handled the situation even better than you did, but don't do it out of guilt because you sabotaged the situation by your clumsiness. I'd have a beer (if you drink beer).

Comment: Don't know, i never downvote answer, no matter how bad it is. I rather put comment, if i find that answer is wrong. Problem in this case is that user didn't have enough reputation to post comment, so he posted answer - and your down vote lowered his reputation even more... Comment, explanation, instead down vote would be better.

Comment: @Jongware He seems to be a legit user with multiple upvoted accepted answers. I dont think they are pity votes by any measure.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who took the time to leave a comment here. You all have provided some great feedback that I'll make sure to keep in mind next time, the most important of which is to disengage with the user earlier. I do see how the conversation wasn't going anywhere so the additional comments weren't really helpful. Thank you all again. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Deduplicator That's a very valid point. Thank you for your comment. I myself thought the part about _rep caps_ covered that. I can understand though, as a new user, how that may not have made sense to him at the time. Solid advice. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Jongware I did see one upvote after I along with three others downvoted that particular answer. I figured that one vote was a pity vote. However, I did look at the user's profile too and he did have some very valid and solid answers so I don't believe the other rep was pity rep. From what I can tell, several of his answers have been accepted so I'd say he earned the additional rep.

Comment: @nevermind I don't usually down vote answers except in the case where (1) the answer is blatantly wrong or has nothing to do with the question asked or (2) when it's clear that the answerer was intentionally trying to circumvent the system, such as posting a comment as an answer instead of waiting until they have the privilege, or the one edge case I've ever found where someone posted a rant as a Community Wiki knowing for well that it would receive a horde of down votes but not wanting to lose any rep. Typically I'll stick with commenting instead.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You were professional and helpful, and (from what I could read before the post was deleted) held a nice neutral tone.  You never attacked the user but offered helpful guidance.  Some people just really don't handle being told they are in the wrong.

So yes, better luck next time.  Keep fighting the good fight.

Comment: Great minds think (and analyze) alike!

Comment: @Kendra I know right? We probably both even both ran into problems upon trying to refresh the deleted answer too ("from what I saw").  Hilarious.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'll keep that in mind for the future. Instead of continuing to comment, which I know can also be frowned upon as a prolonged conversation, I'll probably disengage sooner and flag for attention.

Answer (score 27):

I'll preface my answer by saying that you - and by extension ***WE*** - are not and can not be responsible for how other members *react* to our editorial intervention. Control what you can control, right?

However, when posting comments that are intended to help ease new users into StackWorld™, every interaction comes with a risk that a new user will not receive advice in the spirit in which it is given - exactly the situation you found yourself in today.

You're not alone - many of us have been there.

I've come to believe that we can help defuse potentially emotional exchanges with consistent and well-thought-out messaging. Surely you've noticed messages such as these before:

> - This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can [ask] it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

- If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.
- This is really a comment, not an answer. With sufficient rep, [you will be able to post comments](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173).
- Comments should not be posted as answers on StackOverflow. Users [earn the privilege of commenting](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) by participating through questions, answers and editing activities.
- The list goes on...

IMHO, what could have been handled better from the start was your preparation; the escalation would have been less likely if you had been armed with a set of canned comments containing embedded links to relevant source material such as specific entries in the [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), the site's help pages, and Meta content. Referencing that material reduces the person-to-person friction, and leaves you in a better position to provide additional guidance if requested and appropriate. Having prepared comments at your fingertips helps speed you through your moderating activities, and reduces your own emotional investment in the comments you give, helping *you* maintain a professional mien even if the user on the other end doesn't.

Resources to help prepare comments:

- The [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).
- [Shorthand links](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) to help reference help pages in links.
- Tools (userscripts & browser plugins) on [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/). For example, I currently use the [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116) userscript to manage [my set](//gist.github.com/mogsdad/f7c3bb8b3ce69d75a965) of canned comments. (Keep your eyes open as you go, I see great examples to emulate, every day.)
- [Chat](//chat.stackoverflow.com/). You'll usually find helpful, experienced users in the [SO Tavern](//chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-free-snacks) or the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) rooms who will (joyfully!) let you bounce ideas off them, offer ideas, and commiserate if needed!
- And last but not least, you can always post a question here if your Spidey Senses are warning you of a possibly sticky situation.

#### What if the poster responds negatively

It will happen sometimes, even with a clear comment. You have two options:

1. Reiterate and possibly expand on your first comment.
2. Move on. If the content of the response deserves it, flag it for moderators; otherwise just ignore it.

Bottom line - don't engage with trolls.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post your thoughts. I really like the idea of using tested prefabricated answers to avoid discrepancy. I'll definitely look to do this in the future and make sure I disengage sooner.

Comment: @Mogsdad Woops, that's what I get for skimming the answer.

Answer (score 12):

Clearly you conducted yourself in a very polite and respectful manner once engaged, so, in that regard, well done. However, the first comment wasn't really required as it didn't really explain the why behind the rule.

Often a downvote is enough to deter users from posting comments as answers. This could also have been flagged as it was clearly not an answer, and even with no context a moderator could have identified that. I would suggest in the future for this type of user to just downvote, flag, and move on.

Unfortunately part of the problem with what happened here is what happens frequently. Users who are already bypassing some convention are being confronted and they take it negatively. This usually can cause them to lash out at the system in general or more often than not the user simply raising awareness.

Engaging in comments with users who are already bypassing convention should kind of come with the expectation that they will receive the message with some form of hostility. They more than likely feel like something is unfair and directly targeting them.

If you are going to leave a comment indicating how a user has deviated from community rules, then at least expect a certain amount of retort from them and also try to post some link to the rules up front as opposed to using a brief comment from the start.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to post your thoughts. I can see what you mean about engaging in comments. If the user is blatantly breaking the rules, s/he probably just doesn't care. I'll keep this in mind for next time and move on sooner.