# Rollback of edit that was approved

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rollbacks

Recently, I answered a question that one particular user thinks is terrible and thus my answer is terrible.  He argues that the question was bad, so I edited the title to be more clear with what I thought the user meant (based on the text in the rest of the post).  The edit got 3 approvals, but then this user rolled-back the edit.

My question: **should a rollback be allowed for an edit that was suggested by one person and vetted by three others?**

It seems that the process lets 1 user trump 4 other's opinions.

- [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34422168/c-sharp-design-reason-behind-statement-of-the-form-j-giving-compile-error)
- [My edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10655754)
- [Rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34422168/4)

Comment: Consider this case: A horrible, vandilizing edit is suggested. Three reviewers not paying attention "vet" this edit. A 2k rep user comes and spots the horrible damage. What would you say to this case? Because blocking rollbacks on approved suggested edits would break this scenario. You might not be aware, but there are a _lot_ of bad reviewers in the suggested edits queue right now.

Comment: No, that would go against [the editing privilege at 2k](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Comment: @approxiblue Good point.  It's just frustrating.  In my opinion he made the rollback just to bolster his own arguments rather than trying to help the person asking a question (and future readers).  I know that he could simply edit, but perhaps rollbacks could still follow different rules because of what it implies?  He's not simply editing it, he's undoing changes that 4 other people thought were good.

Comment: We could add your restrictions on rollback, then the user could roll back manually. It's pointless.

Comment: @Kendra that's also a good point, but stack overflow is a voting system. Right?  If the majority of people are going to vote wrong, the whole system would break, right?

Comment: The voting system is a huge part of Stack Overflow, yes- But that's mainly for up/down votes and quality control for posts. For reviews, it's a bit different. You don't get 100s of people able to vote on a single review. Instead, there are measures that can be used to undo a bad review- For instance, a rollback on a bad edit, or reopen votes on a bad closure. It's these reversal mechanisms that make review still work despite the bad apples in the queues. (That, and mods can suspend reviewers once bad reviews come to light.)

Comment: Very closely related: [*Rolling Back Approved Edits*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253365/2751851). (This arguably counts as a dupl*cate; the answer here, though, adds an interesting perspective to the discussion there.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes it should be allowed.  A rollback is little more than a special kind of edit.  There's no sense in preventing more edits to the same post.

Since the other user had full editing privileges (> 2k rep), they didn't have to wait for their edit to be approved like your suggestion had to.  You too can [suggest an edit that is effectively a rollback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268339/how-to-handle-edits-you-think-shouldnt-have-been-made/268340#268340).  You shouldn't get into rollback wars or other edit wars, but there's nothing preventing you from suggesting edits to posts that have already been edited.

> It seems that the process lets 1 user trump 4 other's opinions.

Not really, it's more that a single higher rep user having more power than a lower rep user.  And this is by design since [reputation is a basic measurement of site trust](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).  It's the fact that you don't have full editing privileges and the other user does.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I think this makes sense, even if in this case it's frustrating (in my opinion)

Comment: Yeah.  Whether the rollback was appropriate is a separate issue.  But there shouldn't be anything preventing the rollback itself.

Comment: is there any mechanism on SO for guarding against inappropriate rollbacks?

Comment: Not sure.  I don't think there is anything for detecting single rollbacks.  But IIRC there is one for detecting edit wars of any kind (including rollback wars).  And there's also custom mod flags for egregiously inappropriate edits of any kind, such as a rollback to a revision that is blatantly offense.

Comment: @JohnCarpenter There isn't a way to _prevent_ inappropriate rollbacks, but there are other ways to handle them. 1) Rollback the rollback. This can be a good idea in cases where you talk to the other user and come to an agreement that the rollback was bad. 2) If a user rolls back a good edit and makes the post _worse_ because of it, you can flag the post "In need of moderator attention" and explain that a user made the post worse by rolling back. This is more appropriate for cases where a user rolls back an edit on their own post or when a rollback war starts. Always try to talk it out first.

Comment: (cont. from above) In the case of a rollback war, i.e. the roll back is rolled back, then another rollback occurs, an auto-flag to the mods is raised. In this particular case, it's hard to say- Your edit did make the title better, but I didn't bother to look and see if you could've improved anything else with the post. I would let tempers cool on that post before trying to fix it yourself.

Comment: @Kendra [great minds again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303724/should-i-have-handled-this-situation-better/303725#comment239552_303725) eh?

Comment: Thanks for the comments!  I'll let it sit for a little while, then come back tomorrow and see where it has left off :)

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yeah, we seem to be good at that. :) For instance, you got this answer up before I'd gotten to the answer box to type out my own.

Comment: @Kendra: There's a fundamental difference between "Why does the statement (j++); give a compilation error in C#?" and "C# design reason behind statement of the form (j++); giving compile error?". The first is satisfactorily answered by quoting chapter & verse, the latter needs insight into the design process of the language. Thus, the edit was blatantly inappropriate and properly rolled back. Also see the comments under the question.

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks for the clarification- I'll admit I didn't realize that, so it's probably good that I didn't try to edit it back myself. (I also admit to just glancing through the comments.)